# Conditional jQuery format

Tags: jquery

Would there be a better, cleaner way to write this conditional script? It's doing the same thing basically, except if `cloneVar` has the class "before", it changes which row it's grabbing (first or last) and changes `.insertAfter` to `.insertBefore`.

```
var cloneVar = $(this).parent().parent('.sortable');

if ($(cloneVar).hasClass('before')) {
    var cloneRow = $(cloneVar).find('.sort-group .row:first');

    $(cloneRow).clone(true).insertBefore(cloneRow)
    .addClass('add').removeClass('first')
    .find('input[type=text], textarea').val('')
    .attr('name', function(index, name) {
        return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
            return Number(n) + 1;
        });
    }).parent().find('input, textarea').attr('id', function(index, id) {
        return id.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
            return Number(n) + 1;
        });
    }).parent().find('.delete').removeClass('visible');

    return false;
} else {
    var cloneRow = $(cloneVar).find('.sort-group .row:last');

    $(cloneRow).clone(true).insertAfter(cloneRow)
    .addClass('add').removeClass('first')
    .find('input[type=text], textarea').val('')
    .attr('name', function(index, name) {
        return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
            return Number(n) + 1;
        });
    }).parent().find('input, textarea').attr('id', function(index, id) {
        return id.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
            return Number(n) + 1;
        });
    }).parent().find('.delete').removeClass('visible');

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to chain everything into one huge line. Break it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// move this out to clean up, since you're doing the same thing in both spots
function incrementProp(index, prop) {
    return prop.replace(/(\d+)/, function (fullMatch, n) {
        return Number(n) + 1;
    });
}

var cloneRow;
if (cloneVar.hasClass('before') {
    cloneRow = $(cloneVar).find('.sort-group .row:first');
    insert = "insertBefore";
} else {
    cloneRow = $(cloneVar).find('.sort-group .row:last');
    insert = "insertAfter";
}

cloneRow.clone(true)[insert](cloneRow) // dynamically call function
    .addClass('add').removeClass('first')
    .find('input[type=text], textarea').val('')
    .attr('name', incrementProp).end()
    .find('input, textarea').attr('id', incrementProp)
    .end().find('.delete').removeClass('visible');

return false;
```

Actual question:

- you can build the selector dynamically depending on whether cloneVar has the relevant class.  Then just run the common code
- Use bracket notation with a string to call insertBefore/insertAfter depending on where the new element is going

Additional pointers:

- `cloneVar`/`cloneRow` are already jQuery objects, so you don't need to wrap in jQuery again
- You may want to use [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) instead of `parent` - it reverts to the collection you had before calling `find` and you won't need to change it if you modify your DOM
- You're doing a lot of chaining, but moving the replacement function out can clean it up a lot

Comment: BOOM! That works out great. Thanks Dennis and Dave for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the if for the one part that changes:

```
var cloneRow = $(cloneVar).find('.sort-group .row:' + 
     /* do the check here */ (cloneVar.hasClass('before') ? 'first' : 'last'));

$(cloneRow).clone(true).insertBefore(cloneRow)
.addClass('add').removeClass('first')
.find('input[type=text], textarea').val('')
.attr('name', function(index, name) {
    return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
        return Number(n) + 1;
    });
}).parent().find('input, textarea').attr('id', function(index, id) {
    return id.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
        return Number(n) + 1;
    });
}).parent().find('.delete').removeClass('visible');

return false;
```

The a ? b : c syntax is just shorthand for

```
if (a) { b }; else { c };
```

Comment: `cloneVar` is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to put it in `$()` again.